# Is it possible to generate WCF async service contracts for Silverlight on runtime?

Tags: silverlight, wcf

I have a WCF service contract that reads like:

```
    [ServiceContract(Name = "DummyService") ]
    public interface IDummyService {

        [OperationContract]
        void DoSomething();

        [OperationContract(Name = "SayHello")]
        string SayHello(string message);
    }
```

The WCF service will be consumed by a Silverlight application. I'm finding a way to eliminate the need to manually write async contracts just so I can consume this through a proxy generated by ChannelFactory.

I'm thinking of writing a specialized invoker class. Sample usage is as follows:

```
// create the invoker using the endpoint config and the existing sync contract
var client = new ServiceInvoker<IDummyService>("LeyDummyService_Endpoint");

// invoke the desired service method set the callback, very similar to how 
// JQuery does AJAX calls...
client.Invoke(dummyService => dummyService.SayHello("harley"),
             (result) => MessageBox.Show(result));
```

Have anyone tried this? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Svcutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx)?  It will compose all the async contracts for you.

Comment: Not an option. I hate writing code for those async contracts, hence the question

Answer (score 0):

Totally possible http://servelat.codeplex.com/